# Is this a virus? I found looking through Registry Editor

Tags: virus

Does this look normal? Or are these files a virus?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest not browsing through your registry unless you know what you are doing and have a specific goal and good information guiding you.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a virus.

These entries are normal entries for your normal activity.

Nothing to be concerned about.

That said, there is never any harm running a full scan using Windows Defender.